# How should I report the significance of a spline smooth obtained using mgcv in R?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, curve-fitting, splines, generalized-additive-model

I wish to test whether a spline-based smooth could be replaced by a linear term. I am using the `mgcv` package in R.

Using the example from the [helpfile](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/mgcv/html/smooth.construct.tp.smooth.spec.html):

```
require(mgcv); n <- 100; set.seed(2)
x <- runif(n); y <- x + x^2*.2 + rnorm(n) *.1
## is smooth significantly different from straight line?
summary(gam(y~s(x,m=c(2,0))+x,method="REML")) ## not quite
```

produces the following output:

```
Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
y ~ s(x, m = c(2, 0)) + x

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -0.02133    0.05315  -0.401    0.689    
x            1.18249    0.10564  11.193   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
        edf Ref.df     F p-value  
s(x) 0.9334      8 0.304  0.0781 .
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =   0.91   Deviance explained = 91.1%
REML score = -70.567  Scale est. = 0.012767  n = 100
```

Can I use the "approximate significance of smooth terms" to test the null hypothesis that a spline does not fit the data significantly better than a linear equation?

If so, **how should I report the results** of this test?

Answer (score 1):

Better if you first compute the linear Gaussian fit of your data:

fit1 <- gamV(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3..., family = gaussian, data = GAM, aViz = list(nsim = 50))

and then contrast AIC scores yielded by linear and non-linear fit:

AIC(fit1,fit2)

Now you can just say that those GAMs attained lower AIC scores were performed